# SVN Client post commit hook

Tags: svn, client, hook

Is there an SVN client with post commit hook? Here's what I would like to achieve. Whenever a change has been committed, I would like our build server to automatically update its own copy and then execute unit testing. If there's an SVN client with post commit hook I can implement there the auto update and unit testing. If such SVN client doesn't exist is there other SVN tool that can help me achieve the same goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

post commit hooks are not implemented on the **client**, but on the SVN **server**. See [Implementing repository hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).

Comment: Yep I know, just looking if there's similar functionality on the client. There's this tool called SVN Notifier which notifies the user when someone committed their changes and it offer functionality to update from there. I think it can be set up to execute auto update but it don't have hook or facility of some kind to run custom actions like unit testing.

Comment: Any decent build server (e.g. Bamboo by Atlassian, or Hudson CI) would allow you to hook into a SVN repository and do what you describe (update, build, run unit tests). Check them out.

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look on these stuffs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking in the wrong place. Most build servers I've worked with will either poll your SVN server with an internal client library, or offer some way to trigger a build from an external web interface, which you would implement by building a proper post-commit hook on your server.